# Axis soap logging issue

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

I am trying to print Axis Request and response logs(with current date appended) , in order to achieve the same I have created client-config.wsdd but on each web service call a new log file is getting generated resulting is large log file name.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">
   <handler name="log" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.LogHandler">
      <parameter name="LogHandler.fileName" value="c:/logs/axis.log" />
   </handler>
   <globalConfiguration>
      <requestFlow>
         <handler type="log" />
      </requestFlow>
      <responseFlow>
         <handler type="log" />
      </responseFlow>
   </globalConfiguration>
   <transport name="http" pivot="java:org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender" />
</deployment>
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.